# None of my poses save. Every time I pose my characters arms, they reset and go back to a weird form

Tags: animation

I have been trying to get into first person animating with blender, but every time I try to edit a keyframe this happens: none of my poses save. Every time I pose my characters arms, they reset and go back to this weird form.

https://gyazo.com/46dca4449d15f0395ea69c517dfb0bf9

Comment: You have to insert keyframes by pressing "i".

Comment: It's hard to tell from your video, but it doesn't seem like your are setting a keyframe at frame#1.  I see a marker however, as if it was set before -- might be why it springs back.   So when you change the pose at frame#1, then RMB:Insert_keyframe on position and rotation.  Then it should hold that position.   Alternately, before that, hold mouse over the Timeline area, RMB:Delete_Keyframes to clear everything.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add keyframes. Drag the line on the bottom to the time you want, then press I on your keyboard. Select the one you need, which is probably rotation. Important: drag timeline before you change the position/rotation and add keyframe.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: your welcome dude

Comment: also uhh can you press that little green tick that appears under the down arrow of my answer pls :3

Comment: of course, I upvoted